# Convergence of sequence in uniform and box topologies

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

I am trying the following problem:

$w_1=(1,1,1,1,\ldots)$
$w_2=(0,2,2,\ldots)$
$w_3=(0,0,3,3,\ldots)$  $\cdots$

$x_1=(1,1,1,1,\ldots)$
$x_2=(0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\ldots)$
$x_3=(0,0,\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\ldots)$  $\cdots$

$y_1=(1,0,0,0,\ldots)$
$y_2=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0,0,\ldots)$
$y_3=(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},0\ldots)$  $\cdots$

$z_1=(1,1,0,0,\ldots)$
$z_2=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0,0,\ldots)$
$z_3=(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},0,0\ldots)$  $\cdots$

I have been able to prove that they all are convergent in product topology but have no idea how we can prove for uniform and box topologies. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: @StefanH: No, I don't know how to work with uniform topologies. I do know its definition but don't know how to apply it in this case

Comment: As Brian wrote, you should first show that $(0,0,...)$ is the only possible limit of all those sequences. To do this, take a tuple $y=(y_1,y_2,...)$ with at least one positive coordinate, say $y_k=ϵ>0$. Then see what happens if you put a neighborhood $U$ around $y$ such that pr$_k(U)\not∋0$. Can you show that there are arbitrarily large $a_n$ that are not in $U$?. This would tell you that no sequence converges to $y\ne0$ in the box topology. Could it then converge to $y$ in one of the other topologies?

Answer (score 1):

The last one is the easiest: in all three topologies it’s essentially a sequence in $\Bbb R^2$.

Show that the first is not convergent in the uniform topology and therefore cannot be convergent in the finer box topology. You can do this by showing that the zero sequence is the only possible limit and then showing that it is not the limit in the uniform topology.

For the second and third, show first that the only possible limit in either topology is the zero sequence. Then show that in both cases the zero sequence is the limit in the uniform topology but not in the box topology. You may want to consider the set

$$\prod_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\left(-\frac1{n+1},\frac1{n+1}\right)\;,$$

which is open in the box topology.

Comment: Could you please work out an example for one of the sequences including box and uniform topology as I still don't know where to begin

Comment: @RutherfordMark: Between Stefan’s comment and my hints, you have a pretty complete road map; if they’re not enough to get you started, I suspect that you don’t understand the uniform and box topologies. Can you tell me what a basic open nbhd of the zero sequence looks like in the uniform topology?

Comment: Here for uniform topology we need to show that $d(x_n,0)<\epsilon$ That would give the neighborhood around 0. I do admit that I not very comfortable with the concept of uniform and box topology

Comment: @RutherfordMark: Or more simply, $\langle u_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is in the $\epsilon$-ball around the zero sequence iff $|u_n|<\epsilon$ for every $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Can you see that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $y_n$ is in the $\epsilon$-ball around the zero sequence whenever $n\ge m$? The same is true for the $x$ and $z$ sequences, but not for the $w$ sequence.

Comment: But $y_n$ depends on n. and after that the sequence just has 0 so there would essentially be a "gap" of some sort

Comment: @RutherfordMark: I don’t understand the statement after *so*. Is $y_5$ in the $\frac14$-ball around the zero sequence?

Comment: Yes, it will be because $y_5$ has value 1/5 for finitely many times and then just 0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11042/discussion-between-rutherford-mark-and-brian-m-scott)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott In the uniform topology, every distance is less than or equal to 1 right ?. for the first case if $\epsilon$ > 1, then convergence defn is satisfied, but any open nbhd of (0,0 ..) with $\epsilon$ < 1 does not contain any element from the sequence. Is this the reason for not converging in uniform topology ?

Comment: @Siddharth: No: for instance, the distance between $w_1$ and $w_3$ in the uniform topology is $2$, and the distance between the zero sequence and $w_n$ is $n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. For *every* $\epsilon>0$ the $\epsilon$-ball about the zero sequence contains only finitely many of the $w_n$, but you’re right that for $\epsilon\le 1$ (not just $<1$) it includes none of them.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I didn't understood why the distance is 2. Uniform metric is defined $\rho(x, y) = sup \{ d̄(x_\alpha , y_\alpha ) | \alpha ∈ J \}$, where $d̄(x, y) = min\{|x − y|, 1}\}$. $w_1$ and $w_3$ coordinate wise difference will be reduced by $d̄$ to 1 if it becomes 2. I think I am wrong here. Could you please tell where exactly is it ?

Comment: @Siddharth: I was assuming a different definition of the uniform metric. If.you're bounding it by $1$, then of course the distance is indeed $1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Siddharth: You’re welcome.